# MVC DisplayFormat Date + Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, annotations

I'm trying to display the date in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`, but it doesn't work (of course `yyyy-MM-dd` works fine, problem is with time)

MODEL:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime eventstart { get; set; }
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eventstart, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eventstart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eventstart, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what *does* happen? And why are you trying to display a date as a date and time? If you want a date and time, use `DataType.DateTime`...

Comment: Nothing happens. The field looks like it did not have any annotations.

Comment: So what *is* displayed? And what about the answers to the other questions?

Comment: Displayed just empty field (without any date format)
I tried with `DataType.DateTime`. Still nothing

Comment: @Piter are you initializing the value?

Comment: @Piter can you please post the Controller code?

Comment: Nothing special :) 
 
`// GET: Event/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }`

I need this date annotation only because format input has to agree.

Comment: @Piter try to initialize the property assigning a value and tell me what you see

Comment: @user449689 - im beginner, and i'm not sure what you expect...

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're generating an input with `type="date"`. There's going to be two issues to be aware of with that:

1. As @JonSkeet pointed out, if you want to work with date *and* time, then you need to use `DataType.DateTime`. That will cause the input to be rendered as `type="datetime"`. With an input of type "date", any time component will be discarded at best or at worst will not allow the value to parsed correctly for the browser date control, which brings us to:
2. The HTML5 datetime input types ("datetime", "date", "time") require the value to be in ISO format, i.e. `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`. The browser control will *display* the date/time in the user's local format based on parsing the ISO-formatted date, but it must be given the value in ISO format, first. If it's not, then it treats it as null, and will show the input value as empty.

Comment: Note that HTML5 `type="datetime"` is not currently supported (refer [comparison](https://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-44/firefox-40/ie-11.html))

Comment: I think the only solution is 3 properties. 
First: 
`[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime eventstart { get; set; }`

Second: 
`[DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime eventstart { get; set; }`

Third:
Merging first and second property

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.eventstart, 
                new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

To:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.eventstart, 
                new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type="date" } })
```

Sure it will work.